# php chmod usage

Tags: php, chmod

I'm trying to write a php file and set permission for it in order to be editable straight away after its creation.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$var = '<?php $mycontent = new Content(); echo $mycontent->block($p_name);?>';

$myFile = "testFile.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $var;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);

chmod("tests/testFile.php", 0644);

?>
```

For some reason it's not working. The created file is still not editable unless I set manually the permissions. tests/ is the directory where the file has been created.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myFile = "testFile.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
chmod("tests/testFile.php", 0644);
```

The functions you are calling are referring to two different files. One in the directory of your PHP script and one in a directory called tests. Choose one, update your code and see if it works out for you.

Comment: the script that creates the file is in the same folder where the file is created. I tried this but is not working: $myFile = "testFile.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
chmod("testFile.php", 0644);

Comment: Have you tried setting it to 0777, or checking the file permissions manually afterwards to see if the script is actually affecting the right file?

Comment: remember that if you manually create the file for testing, the owner will be different that it would if the script created the file. That is likely why it must be `0777`. let the script test if the file is there, if not create it, then proceed with safer permissions.